# How to setup a simple local linux proxy that caches all HTTP requests for offline browsing

Tags: linux, caching, networking, browser, proxy

is there a simple way to setup a local proxy on a linux pc that caches ALL HTTP requests in ANY case ('hard refresh' ..., after some time ...), if it has loaded the resource ONCE, configurable by URL/host patterns white list / black list? There should be a possibility to clear the cache for specific resources or at least to clear the complete cache by cli command or web interface.

Thanks in advance
AJ

Answer (score 1):

With "ALL requests " you probably mean HTTP requests, right?

In this case `squid` is an product for that. It is easy to set up and provides a lot of features, including an very persistent/stubborn caching behaviour.

If you use ubuntu, you can find here an tutorial for quick startup: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html

Btw: squid is an very powerful tool. Depending on your needs lightweight alternative could fit your needs, like [Lighttpd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighttpd)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, I mean http / https requests, but none of the tools are working for me. lighttpd is a webserver / reverse proxy. Polipo and Squid are generally caching the pages, but they don't do, what they should do for me. Even in offline_mode they try to fetch the page, which doesn't work if I am not connected to the internet. I need a proxy (not reverse proxy) that caches ALL http requests and returns future request from cache, if the page was cached once, ignoring any cache control headers.

Comment: Maybe it's an good idea to ask that as an specific squid question in "superUser" board.    ...Grüße nach Hamburg